# Devise Warden undefined method `sign_out' for main:Object

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, warden

Upgrading from Rails 3 to 4 and Devise 3.1.1 to 3.2.1, getting this strange error. Backtrace [here](https://gist.github.com/KevinTriplett/7595138)

I have three scopes, :client, :admin, :super_user. :super_user is timeoutable and it has timed out, causing this error. I've been trying to debug for the past day and since this is in the guts of middleware and Devise/Warden, I have no clue how to debug.

Here's the [Warden code in Devise](https://gist.github.com/KevinTriplett/7595209) where it fails, at line 16 in the false leg of the ternary.

Any suggestions what I should look at or try? It's bound to be somewhere in the way I [configure devise](https://gist.github.com/KevinTriplett/7595185) or my [model configuration](https://gist.github.com/KevinTriplett/7595193). Thanks for any help. :/

Comment: Not really the answer you're looking for, but you can debug your bundled Devise with the command `bundle open devise`.

Comment: Might have to `include DeviseControllerSignInOut` in your warden file to called `sign_out` method since it only accessible to controller . even better use `warden.logout(scope)` instead of `sign_out(scope)` even `sign_out(scope)` internally call that check [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/c67de7e91cc3ea201c7cedc0ed71e1f6c76b2d36/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L62)